# Using a hashmap and simple adapter in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am trying to use a hashmap to show some data in a list view via a fragment in a practice app I am making. The hashmap worked previously however when I switched to a fragment I am getting an error. Do I need to rewrite this somehow now I am using fragments?

I have attached the code where I am having the problem however I am getting error signs in the brackets at new SimpleAdapter

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(layout.home_fragment, null);

    ListView recipesListView = (ListView) view.findViewById(id.recipesListView);

    HashMap<String, String> recipes = new HashMap<>();
    recipes.put("Bangers and Mash", "Sausages, Potatoes, Gravy \n\nCook the sausages in a pan and boil the potatoes then mash them put on a plate and pur gravy on them");
    recipes.put("Spaghetti Carbonara", "Bacon, Onions, Spaghetti, Eggs, Cream \n\nCook bacon, onions in a pan and boil spaghetti, once cooked pour in eggs and cook on high until ready");
    recipes.put("Chicken and Bacon Sandwich", "Chicken, Bacon, Mayonnaise, Lettuce, Bread, Butter\n\nButter the bread and spread mayonnaise on it. Put the chicken and bacon between the bread");

    List<HashMap<String, String>> listRecipes = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, listRecipes, layout.list_items,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.recipeTitle, R.id.method});

    Iterator it = recipes.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> resultsMap = new HashMap<>();
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        resultsMap.put("First Line", pair.getKey().toString());
        resultsMap.put("Second Line", pair.getValue().toString());
        listRecipes.add(resultsMap);
    }

    recipesListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    return view;
}


}
```

}

Thanks for any help which can be offered.

Comment: Post your error. Pls!

Comment: add your SimpleAdapter  constructor

Comment: my guess is use new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), listRecipes, layout.list_items,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.recipeTitle, R.id.method}); intsead of  new SimpleAdapter(this, listRecipes, layout.list_items,
            new String[]{"First Line", "Second Line"},
            new int[]{R.id.recipeTitle, R.id.method});

Comment: Hey everyone thanks for the very quick responses however Adeel that worked perfectly and it makes sense to me now. Thanks so much!